# Добавление новых новостей в CoreData

Tags: json, ios, objective-c

Есть json, который получаю с сайта. В каждом объекте из этого json есть ИД новости. Нужно при запуске приложения получать новые новости и заносить их в CoreData.

Правильный ли алгоритм?:

1. Беру максимальное число (максимальный ИД новости, т.е. последней новости) из Core Data.
2. Получаю новый json (примерно 200 новостей).
3. Парсим его.
4. Загоняем объекты json в массив и сортируем (по ИД новостей).
5. Находим в массиве этот ИД.
6. Отсекаем старые (удаляем) объекты из массива вместе с найденным ИД последней новости.

С этого назревает вопрос:

1. Будет ли это быстро работать?
2. Как можно отсечь часть массива "пакетом", не проходя в цикле и не удаляя ненужный элемент за элементом?

Спасибо.

Comment: @iSerg, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Кстати, т.к. насчет алгоритма? Верным ли путем иду?

Comment: @iSerg, вполне, имхо)
Тут вариантов реализации может быть 100500, так что пробуйте/дерзайте)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что на счет этого:

```
- (void)removeObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
```

Comment: Спасибо. Нужно будет еще и это: - (void)removeObject:(id)anObject inRange:(NSRange)aRange попробовать.

или даже - (void)removeObjectsInRange:(NSRange)aRange

Comment: @iSerg, всегда пожалуйста. Просто сначала всегда просматривайте доки епловские, хотя бы - ответ придет сам собой ;)